# what does "I'm good on puffs" in the below conversation?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> A: Do you want some bean-curd puffs?
>
> B: No, I'm good on puffs.

Is that an idiom?

Comment: Can you provide context.  Who said this?

Comment: Some kind of breakfast cereal, probably.  He or she is saying they have enough in their bowl.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like an AmE variation of "I'm good for puffs"  This is a casual way to say "I have sufficient puffs".  (Which could mean I don't have any puffs, but that's okay, because I don't want any.)  There are several meanings of "good for" and "good on", and you have to infer the right one by context.

This, or the shorter form  "I'm good" can be used as a colloquial but polite way to reject an offer.   [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/good) has an example:

> "More coffee?" "No, I'm good, thanks."

It is discussed on a blog [When “I’m good” is “no, thanks”](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/06/good.html)

Comment: *Sometimes*,  "I have sufficient X" might mean *I haven't actually got **any** X - but that's okay, because **I don't want any X***.

Comment: This may be a regional difference but **I'm good on puffs** sounds perfectly natural to this US English speaker, and "I'm good **for** puffs" sounds wrong.  The only way I can see using *I'm good for puffs* would be to mean "I am a reliable source for puffs."